# map better than sparse vector?

Tags: c++, memory, dictionary, vector

I have 2 objects:

```
vector<string> v(999999);
map<int, string> m;
```

I need to store some index-string pairs, though it's very sparse (say only 20 pairs). I was wondering if the **vector** takes much more memory than **map**? If so, how much memory is vector taking up? And why is it bad to use vector in this case?

Comment: That's not a sparse vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the vector will take up at least `999999 * (sizeof(string) + C) + sizeof(vector)` bytes in practice (where `C` is any dynamic allocation automatically performed by `string`).  The `map` will have overhead, but it definitely won't be anywhere near the order of 999999.

Comment: You may not be able to access the elements of that map in key order depending on its implementation.

Comment: @Peter Wooster if that is a requirement, one could keep a separate vector with map iterators in correct order.

Comment: I agree that a separate list of keys would be needed, I believe this is what third party sparse array systems usually do.  It would need to allow inserts, so a linked list instead of an array would be needed.

Comment: @PeterWooster: `std::map` requires the keys to be iterated in key/predicate order.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use vector if look up time is *absolutely* critical, since it is constant on vector, effectively pointer arithmetics since you know index already, but grows with size on map (O(log n)). Circumstances need to be dire indeed for that kind of a tradeoff though.

Answer (score 1):

For about 20 elements there is no point in creating a vector with 10^6 elements. The use of a map is going to have much better memory footprint and may even be faster than the vector. You can also consider a mixed approach with a vector of `std::pair<int,std::string>` holding the key/value pairs and do linear search on the vector (20 elements are **very few**, few enough that you can consider the cost as constant, and the simpler algorithm probably compensates for the extra number of operations).